# Centering and positioning, a css nightmare

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have a task that I initially thought would be easy, but turned out to be quite difficult. I want to be able to detect the height of the current visible window, center some text in that section of visible window, and place a navigation bar at just the end of the window, so a graphic of what it would look the following:

[image]

I have tried various ways of doing this, including setting the height of a div to a certain vh level and centering text inside that dif, though that was quite problematic, as vh is not supported in ie 8 and in order to center the text inside the div, many sources told me to do position: absolute, which tended to shift the text to a corner, which I did not want.

Is there a way in which I can create such a display? If I worded anything incorrectly or posted in the wrong place, please let me know. Thanks in advance for any help.

edit: here is the code I am using: http://pastelink.me/dl/b3cb50

Also some snippets of code for clarification:

what I do is I have a div with height of 100vh and width of 100% and an h1 with an id of myTitle (the css for id myTitle just sets the `text-align` to `center`)

```
<div style="height: 100vh; width: 100%"><h1 id="myTitle"> This is a large title!</h1></div>
```

and a nav bar directly below it, using foundation's nav bar code:

```
<nav class="top-bar" id="myNav" data-topbar>
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name"><h1><a href="#ranadheer">My Site</a></h1></li>
        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section"> <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
            <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

EDIT: Many answers were said regarding setting the position of the nav bar to the bottom, and I thank you for that, though I forgot to clarify one thing. I would like for the nav bar to only be at the bottom initially, and when someone scrolls down it moves up, and does not stay fixed to the bottom.

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Please do not make us download your code

Comment: I suggest to put your code in a way is easy to edit and show the results like using http://plnkr.co/edit/

Answer (score 0):

find

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
...
</div>
```

and change it to

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
...
</div>
```

bootstrap has a fixed top and bottom selectors :)

Answer (score 0):

#### [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/meyox/1/edit)

Is this what you need? A table is the most supported method for vertical align in CSS.

```
.table {
  display: table;
  min-height: 100vh; width: 100%;
}
.table div {
  display: table-row;
}
.header {
  height: 90px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.header h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.content p {
  padding: 0 1em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.footer {
  height: 220px;
  background: #ddd;  
}
```